# How to get values inside while loop and put it outside c# winform Crystal report

Tags: c#

I've been searching this page and other pages in this matter. I know it's not possible to get the data inside the while loop with direct assigning of variables, so I've tried to put it to label before and it works but only to the first value of the `finalcred` and `finaldeb`. It will not reset to fetch another value, so my real question is; Is there any other way to get the value inside the while loop and use it outside?

I have tried to declare it outside while and assign default value and the result will always be the default. It will not change.

```
r = t.NewRow();
//somecode..all good here
while (counterdate <= monthval)
{
    //allgood in this part
    totalcred = 0;
    totaldeb = 0;
    balance = 0;
    crednum = 0;
    debnum = 0;

    if (readgetcode1.HasRows)
    {
        while (readgetcode1.Read())
        {
            readgetcred.Read();
            readgetdeb.Read();

            if (readgetdeb.HasRows)
            {
                debnum = Convert.ToDecimal(readgetdeb.GetValue(0));
            }
            else
            {
                debnum = 0;
            }

            if (readgetcred.HasRows)
            {
                crednum = Convert.ToDecimal(readgetcred.GetValue(0));
            }
            else
            {
                crednum = 0;
            }

            totalcred += crednum;
            totaldeb += debnum;

            if (strType == "Debit")
            {
                balance = totaldeb - totalcred;
            }
            else
            {
                balance = totalcred - totaldeb;
            }

            allbal += balance;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        allbal = 0;
    }

    if (readprevCred.HasRows)
    {
        prevBalNum = Convert.ToDecimal(readprevBal.GetValue(0));
    }
    else
    {
        prevBalNum = 0;
    }

    if (strType == "Debit")
    {
        finaldeb = prevBalNum + allbal;
        finalcred = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        finalcred = prevBalNum + allbal;
        finaldeb = 0;
    }

    counterdate++;
}//while counterdate looping

r["accntCode"] = codevalue;
r["accntName"] = accntnameval;
r["DebitAmount"] = finaldeb;//this is the problem
r["CreditAmount"] = finalcred;;//this is the problem
t.Rows.Add(r);

//while readcodecheck in counter for code
```

Comment: Is problem solved now?

Comment: Not yet sir @chetan

Comment: Are you sure that finalcred and finaldeb have different value after first loop?

Comment: yes, at first loop, the value is -2 and the second loop is -1 and the third loop is -1. that should be the value if i select the month of February. the result should be -2,-1,-1.. maybe the problem here is in the `balance` and `allbal` .. but everytime i debug.. the value showing are all -2. .  @GeorgeAlexandria

Comment: the outpud should be like this

Comment: You check **if(readprevCred.HasRows)** and get value from **readprevBal** (after counting allbal). Is it rigth? And I don't see where you change **readprevBal** in the outer loop. So, does prevBalNum have the same value for all loop?

Comment: `prevCred = "SELECT CreditAmount FROM TBPrevBal where accntCode='" + codevalue + "' and AccountType='" + fundtypesw + "'";`   that is for `readprevcred` sql    and `prevBal = "SELECT Balance FROM TBPrevBal where accntCode='" + codevalue + "' and AccountType='" + fundtypesw + "'";`  this is for `readprevbal`  i think they will produce the same result, i just forgot to edit the `if` part, but the loop result is the same.

Comment: and for the `prevbalnum`   yes they all have the same value, because its the closing balance for the previous year e.g 2016. so lets say accntcode1 have 50 balance from previous year 2016. so if January2017 lets say it has the balance of -1 and in february got the balance of -1, if i choose february, the result should be =50+-1+-1